# How to use index of with parsing in Java

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

I have a line of string with a specific format that has given me troubles. I want to take the line of string below:

```
String data = "[{\'ID\': 0001, \'Name\': Black Shirt, \'Cost\': 3.00, \'Asle\':1},{\'ID\': 0002, \'Name\': White Shirt, \'Cost\': 2.00, \'Asle\':1}]";
```

I want to output the ID and the Cost:

```
0001
3.00
0002
2.00
```

This is what I have:

```
String data = "[{\'ID\': 0001, \'Name\': Black Shirt, \'Cost\': 3.00, \'Asle\':1},{\'ID\': 0002, \'Name\': White Shirt, \'Cost\': 2.00, \'Asle\':1}]";
String[] token = data.split("\'ID");
int firstindex = data.indexOf(",");
int lastindex = data.indexOf("");
String Id = null;
String Cost;
int i =1;
for(String s : token) {
    if (i==1) {
        Id = s.replaceFirst(data.substring(firstindex + 1, lastindex + 4), "");
        i++;
    } else {
        Cost = s.replaceFirst(data.substring(firstindex + 1, lastindex + 4), "");
    }
    System.out.print(Id);
    System.out.print(Cost);
}
```

I get the following error when I try and run it.

```
String index out of range: -9
```

I also get an error abut not being able to index Cost, and I am not sure why I can't set it the same way I did with Id. If you could please tell me how you got that answer that would be great. I want to make sure I get a firm understanding of string before I go on asking others for help.

Comment: That is JSON, you should be using a JSON parser, which will handle all the subtle details of parsing JSON.

Comment: It would be much easier to use a JSON parser, like Jackson.

Comment: 1. What do you expect to have here? 

    int lastindex = data.indexOf(""); it is always 0. So substring crashes. Then you never changes your firstindex, lastindex inside for loop. it does not matter how many tokens you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try code below. I think it can achieve exactly what you want to do.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String...strings) {
        String data = "[{\'ID\': 0001, \'Name\': Black Shirt, \'Cost\': 3.00, \'Asle\':1},{\'ID\': 0002, \'Name\': White Shirt, \'Cost\': 2.00, \'Asle\':1}]";

        int idFrom, idTo, costFrom, costTo;
        String idStr = "{\'ID\': ";
        String nameStr = ", \'Name\': ";
        String costStr = ", \'Cost\': ";
        String asleStr = ", \'Asle\'";
        while(data.indexOf(idStr) != -1) {
            idFrom = data.indexOf(idStr) + idStr.length();
            idTo = data.indexOf(nameStr);
            System.out.println(data.substring(idFrom, idTo));
            costFrom = data.indexOf(costStr) + costStr.length();
            costTo = data.indexOf(asleStr);
            System.out.println(data.substring(costFrom, costTo));
            data = data.substring(costTo + asleStr.length());
        }
    }
}
```

And as the comments memtioned, JSON parser like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) will make your life much easier.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking into using Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Gson**

```
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(data);
JsonArray jarray = jelement.getAsJsonArray();
for(int i=0;jarray.size();i++){
    JsonObject  jobject = jarray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    String id = jobject.get("ID")..toString();
    String name = jobject.get("Name").toString();
    double cost = jobject.get("Cost").getAsDouble();
    String asle = jobject.get("Asle").toString();
}
```